# AWS RDS .NET SDK ModifyDBInstance not working for SQL Server engine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using [this AWS .Net SDK function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=RDS/MRDSModifyDBInstanceModifyDBInstanceRequest.html) to modify a SQL Server database instance. I am NOT trying to update the storage capacity as I know it cannot be done on SQL Server. However, any call to modify any other field fails with the following error:

> AllocatedStorage cannot be modified for DB Instances with this engine: sqlserver-ex

I'm not even setting the AllocatedStorage property on the ModifyDBInstanceRequest object, but it defaults to 0 as it is of type int.

I can successfully modify a MySQL database engine with the same function.

Here's the code I am using.

```
ModifyDBInstanceRequest request = new ModifyDBInstanceRequest();
if (storageAllocation.HasValue) { request.AllocatedStorage = (int)storageAllocation; }
request.MasterUserPassword = masterUserPassword;
//all the other request values...
ModifyDBInstanceResponse response = ConnectionCache.GetRDSClient(awsCredential).ModifyDBInstance(request);
```

Comment: Are you 100% positive that `storageAllocation` is NULL? Try removing the `if (storageAllocation.HasValue) { request.AllocatedStorage = (int)storageAllocation; }` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To a "viewer" of the request object, `AllocatedStorage` may appear to be 0 by default, but internally there's an "is set" value of false. Meaning that in the structure it's 0, but it won't be sent up during the request.

Even if you are not changing the allocated storage, if you are setting the `AllocatedStorage` value, the SDK will interpret that as an attempted change attempt and fail.

You must completely avoid setting the `AllocatedStorage` property to any value, even to a value that matches the currently allocated storage on your RDS instance.